# New session when the lockscreen shows up (or when my laptop goes in standby)

Tags: release-loki, greeter

I'm running ElementaryOS Loki since yesterday and I'm very pleased so far, there is just one annoyance that I couldn't figure out.

I get a new session (as in: no programs open and a completely empty desktop) when my laptop turns on the lock screen or when I close my laptop (stanby)

A few notes & specs:

- In Ubuntu 16.04 (which I had before Loki) this didn't happen.
- There is no error shown, just an empty desktop when I enter my password again.
- I have the 64bit version and enabled home folder encryption.
- My laptop is the Transformer Book T300 CHI with all upgrades (8GB ram, 128GB SSD and 2560x1440 resolution, Intel Core M)

Thanks in advance, can post any info when needed! :)

Comment: Can you post the part of your `/var/log/syslog` when this happens?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer when I can safely reproduce this (am now working xD)

Comment: @lemonslice here is my syslog just after doing standby and waking up: http://pastebin.com/DYe4DJh7

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!
Downside: I'm still with the ugly looking white reactangle for the login, even after reinstalling pantheon-greeter and deleted unity-greeter. Did you get pantheon-greeter back?

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of research because nobody was really replying anymore, and came with a solution, but it's a hard workaround, at least it works, but if you have a better solution, I will accept that answer.

Not all steps have to be nessecary but I don't have the time to further check it out.

Here is what I did:

- I removed pantheon-greeter and installed unity-greeter.
- After reboot I reversed the process again
- Then in settings I declared this new hotkey: 
  [image]

Now I can lock and unlock!